# Listing/Referencing Specific Bookmarks in Python script tool?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, python-script-tool, bookmarks

I'm trying to create three map layouts and export them into PDFs using ModelBuilder in ArcGIS Pro. However, when I try to reference the three bookmarks (AAA, Amityville, and Astoria) to be used for the layouts, I get an error.

Here is a section of my code from a custom script tool that I am having trouble with:

```
# setting layout to bookmark
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("Current")

# add name of layout
lyt = aprx.listLayouts("Layout_King")[0]
mf = lyt.listElements("MAPFRAME_ELEMENT")[0]

# add name of bookmark
bkmks = mf.map.listBookmarks('AAA','Amityville','Astoria')
bkmks.sort(key=lambda x: x.name, reverse=True)
for bkmk in bkmks:
  mf.zoomToBookmark(bkmk)
  legend.autoAdd = True
  time.sleep(5)
  lyt.exportToPDF(r"C:\arcGIS_Shared\Exports" + "\\" + bkmk.name + ".pdf")
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\arcGIS_Shared\PythonTest_2\Layout_Bookmark_Export_Script.py", line 42, in <module>
    bkmks = mf.map.listBookmarks('AAA','Amityville','Astoria')
TypeError: listBookmarks() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
Failed to execute (Layout Bookmark Export)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/map-class.htm), `listBookmarks` can take a wildcard to search on.  You cannot pass three parameters to it, like you are doing.

Try something like:

```
bkmks = mf.map.listBookmarks('A*')
```

One alternative would be to retrieve all the bookmarks, then in your loop below, check to see if they are in your list.

```
# add name of bookmark
bkmks = mf.map.listBookmarks()
bkmks.sort(key=lambda x: x.name, reverse=True)
for bkmk in bkmks:
  if bkmk.name in ['AAA','Amityville','Astoria']:
       mf.zoomToBookmark(bkmk)
       legend.autoAdd = True
       time.sleep(5)
       lyt.exportToPDF(r"C:\arcGIS_Shared\Exports" + "\\" + bkmk.name + ".pdf")
```

Note: this is untested code.